# man 7 groff_man - No manual entry for groff

Tags: linux, manpage, groff, troff

I am wanting to view more information on the Groff Macro Packages through my Man Page viewer. However, when I try to see them, they do not work.

```sh
➜  man groff
# [...works as expected...]
➜  man 7 groff               
No manual entry for groff in section 7
➜  man 7 groff_man
No manual entry for groff_man in section 7
```

Where do I find that macro package documentation or what packages do I need to install?

Comment: You can always look at the online man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff_man.7.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that even though the `groff` application is present on the machine, all of the other supporting docs are not. For Fedora, I needed to install the following packages.

```sh
sudo dnf install groff groff-base groff-doc groff-perl groff-x11
```

After doing that, I was able to execute

```sh
man 7 groff_man
```

and get the information I needed.

Comment: On my system installing `groff` was enough. BTW IMO this kind of questions are more appropriate on `unix.stackexchange.com`